# boost::this_thread::sleep_for sleeps much longer than I expect.

Tags: c++, boost

I used boost sleep_for in my multithread project and found that it slept much longer than I expect.

statement like this :

```
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```

It might take 0.1 second or 2 seconds and even 10 seconds.

But in my test program, it works fine.

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        auto start = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        auto end = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();

        std::cout << (end-start).count() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on Mac Os 10.10 with clang-602.0.53 and Boost version is 1.58.

Comment: Use sleep_until if you want a stronger guarantee you'll be woken by some deadline. sleep_for only gives a best effort sleep, it could be no sleep or a sleep far longer than requested.

Comment: Tested sleep_until.  Same result as sleep_for. [Seems like both of these functions don't give me a guarantee. ](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until)

Comment: The other thing is to try Boost latest. There were a few bugs in the timer calculation a few releases ago. I'll admit honestly they were introduced by me :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I found that it should not be a boost issue. My application is a Qt application and this issue doesn't show if I remove all Qt code. I got another answer saying that it's caused by OS X's App Nap feature. I'm looking into it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053980/thread-cannot-wake-in-qt-application?noredirect=1#comment55864790_34053980

Answer (score 1):

Boost's `sleep_for` uses the POSIX [nanosleep()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nanosleep.html) function on most non-Windows platforms ([source](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/develop/src/pthread/thread.cpp)). It's up to the kernel to decide when to wake up the suspended thread.

If there's significant activity on the system (lots of threads doing lots of work) then it may take a while for the OS' thread scheduler to get around to waking up a thread. `nanosleep()` only guarantees that your thread won't be woken up before the specified duration--it makes no guarantees about accuracy after the duration has elapsed.

I bet if you change your test program to spawn a large number of worker threads that are doing a lot of work (something more computationally intensive than calling `now()`) then the accuracy will plummet.