# Thread cannot wake in Qt application.

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, qt

I have an issue about `sleep_for` in my Qt application and it can be reproduced in this test program.

The `sleep_for` always returns in 1 second if the test program has the focus. If the test program loses the focus, `sleep_for` still returns normally in the first minute, but then it sleeps for around 10 seconds every time.

I tried to use `nanosleep` instead of sleep_for , or use std thread instead of QThread. Got the same issue.

If I uncommented Qt code , the sleep problem is gone.

I'm so confused now. Does OS give dead loop thread a penalty ?

I'm on Mac OS X 10.10 with Qt 5.5.1 and clang-602.0.53.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>


int sleep_test(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        //nanosleep((const struct timespec[]){{1, 0}}, nullptr);
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        std::cout << (end-start).count() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

class QtSleepThread : public QThread
{
    public:
        void run()
        {
            sleep_test();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

#if 0
    std::thread t(sleep_test);
    t.join();

#else
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    //std::thread t(sleep_test);
    QtSleepThread t;
    t.start();

    app.exec();
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you may be running into OS/X's infamous "App Nap" feature.  Try running Activity Monitor, right-clicking on the header of its Processes table to expose the "App Nap" column, and then watching your program's row in that table while reproducing the fault.  If you see the "App Nap" value turn to "Yes", then it's probably App Nap that is causing your timing to be slow.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Disabled App Nap and the issue disappeared.